# Website background responsive

Tags: html, css, background

Im using this code:

```
body {
background-image:url('http://evoxity.net/modules/themeconfigurator/img/bgen.jpg')!important;
background-repeat:no-repeat!important;
-webkit-background-size:cover!important;
-moz-background-size:cover!important;
-o-background-size:cover!important;
background-size:fixed!important;
background-position:center!important;
}
```

I tried to create it responsive and its workign so far but it should be more static. My problem is, that my website software doesnt feature container background by default and im not that deep into css to do it by my self so i decided to create it on the background.

Now i would like to work with @media but i also would like to get this background keeping how it is even if i add the windwos bar to the right/left site of the browser.

I used a module for that website software to create backgrounds and it can implement them in css as well but i dont know the id of it so i cant modify it with css. Thats the reason why i do it now by my own.

To get the question on a point again. If you have a 1920x1080 resolution screen and drag your windows bar to one of the sites, the background moves but it should stay static and just get cuttet on the right site than it works.

Comment: [Do you mean fixed?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/qDx2u/)

Comment: Its not realy about what i mean :D i tryed that "background-attachment:fixed;" out of your link but it doesnt help. I dont know how that thing is called so i cant tell you how to change it.

Comment: Well i did fix it by deleting the "webkit-background-size"

Answer (score -1):

To achieve a static background image that gets cut off on the right side when the browser window is resized and the windows bar is added to the sides,

- modify your existing CSS code and
- use media queries.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://evoxity.net/modules/themeconfigurator/img/bgen.jpg') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  -moz-background-size: cover !important;
  -o-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: fixed !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}

/* Use media queries to modify the background size when the window is smaller */
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    background-size: 1920px 1080px !important; /* Set the size to your desired resolution */
  }
}
```

**What this code do:**

This CSS code sets the background image to cover the entire viewport with a center position, making it responsive. However, using the `@media` query, it adjusts the background size to match the specified resolution (in this case, 1920x1080) when the viewport width is less than or equal to 1920px.

So in this way, the background image will stay static within the specified resolution, and if the browser window is resized further, the image will be cut off on the right side.

**Note:** You can adjust the `1920px` value in the media query to match the width at which you want the background to become static and cut off on the right side.

Hope it helps.