# Make image size for background

Tags: html, css

Hi I am building a website and I have an image that I want to use as a background image for a portion of the site. As you scroll the image scrolls. I simply want to resize the image in my CSS to fit to the portion of the screen... CAn someone help me? its more challenging then it seems.

```
#stat, #newsletter 
{
background: url('../img/worklogo.png') center bottom no-repeat; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please see this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435059/website-background-responsive/24440336#24440336

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `background-attachment: fixed;` and use `background-image:url('');`
instead of `background:url('');`.
Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V6gv7/2/).