# Making a website logo flexible for different devices while keeping it centered

Tags: html, css

My last question in terms of CSS was this one:

[Website background responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435059/website-background-responsive)

it was about a responsive background and i got this one fixed after a long research. I tryed to use some of what i learned and got it nearly working as good as i wanted but(!) i messed something up.

```
<style type="text/css">
.logo {
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
</style>

<img src="https://www.google.com.tw/images/srpr/logo11w.png"  class="logo"/>
```

just to keep it simple i put both together. As you may not see in a fiddle or something like this. It is working somehow fine in lower resolutions but if i screenshot it on my 1920x1080 screen and just check the left to the logo and right to the logo difference in photoshop i can clearly see that the difference from the right border to the logo is larger than from the opposite site.

I realy appreciate some ideas!

Comment: your logo container should have `text-align:center` and your container logo should have a max-width , in different devices.So your logo will not look stretched

Comment: On screenfly it doesnt look stretched on any device. Since max-width:100% just allow the logo to be as width as it was designed it should work. Also a "text-align: center;" is here. Not sure if i did understand something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `max-width: x%` and `max-height: x%` keeps the image in the correct proportions when resizing (Keep the percentage size the same for both).

Making the image `display: table` allows the flexible width image to be centered with `margin: 0 auto`

In this example, the image is 400px x 400px with a max-width / max-height set at 40%. This is just to make the re-size obvious for the demo. Open it full screen and re-size the window to see the shrink.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.logo {
  display: table;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="http://www.placehold.it/400">
```